# htaccess Not Contain Google Tracking Code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have setup a mobile redirect code in the htaccess file for a subdirectory of my site. It works in all aspects but when coming from Google Maps and Google Adwords. I realized that tracking is setup and that seems to be causing the incorrect redirect on desktops. I am trying to add a negative/not contain line as a RewriteCond for the tracking url tag of ?gclid=XXXXXXXXX

The URL varies each time but would essentially be something like 
www.example.com/location/?gclid=A1B2C3D4

Here is what i have. Please let me know if this is correct.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(gclid)[NC]
RewriteRule ^location$ http://subdomain.example.com/mobile-location [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^location/(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/mobile-location [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

gclid is a variable in a query string. You cannot match it through `%{REQUEST_URI}` as that contains everything behind the domain name (including the slash) and before the query string. In `http://localhost/pretty/penguins?are=pretty` it would match against `/pretty/penguins`.

You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}`. The entire thing would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !gclid [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android [NC]
RewriteRule ^location$ http://subdomain.example.com/mobile-location [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^location/(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/mobile-location [L,R=302]
```

Comment: So i tried this line of code and it took down the website. Not sure what the issue is with it, but it was that line that caused it to go down. Any ideas?

Comment: "go down" = ?; Find your error_log and see what was the actual error it logged.

Comment: Ok so the code was corrected but it still isnt doing what I hoped it would. Since the query string is more than just the gclid, would that mean we need anything before or after gclid? 
If the string is ?gclid=A1B2C3D4 and we only have gclid in the Cond, will that create a problem in finding all results containing gclid?

Comment: A regex can match part of a variable if that is what you are asking, so unless you limit my solutions by adding `^` or `$` somewhere then this condition should match any request **not** containing the string "gclid" in the query string.

Comment: Well then this code did not work and the gclid tagged/tracked pages are still redirecting the the mobile site. Any ideas on how to write this differently to get it to stop recognizing a Google tracking code as a mobile device?